# Blank time series plot with Panel / Vega

Tags: python, plot, checkbox, time-series

as you can see in the picture (datfarme) I want to plot a time series plot (for total vaccinations per date ) with a check box filter for the countries (i have 60 country in my dataset ) but all i get is a blank plot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNpl2.png)

This is my code :

```
    import panel as pn
    import altair as alt
    from altair import datum
    import pandas as pd
    from vega_datasets import data
    import datetime as dt
    
    alt.renderers.enable('default')
pn.extension('vega')
df2 = df.copy()
# create list of countries (tickers) to use as options
tickers = ['Argentina', 'Austria', 'Bahrain', 'Belgium' ,'Brazil', 'Bulgaria' ,'Canada',
 'Chile' ,'China' ,'Costa Rica' ,'Croatia' ,'Cyprus', 'Czechia', 'Denmark',
 'Ecuador', 'England' ,'Estonia' ,'Finland', 'France' ,'Germany', 'Gibraltar',
 'Greece' ,'Hungary', 'Iceland', 'India', 'Indonesia' ,'Ireland' ,'Isle of Man',
 'Israel' ,'Italy' ,'Kuwait' ,'Latvia' ,'Lithuania' ,'Luxembourg' ,'Malta',
 'Mexico', 'Netherlands', 'Northern Ireland' ,'Norway' ,'Oman' ,'Panama',
 'Poland' ,'Portugal', 'Romania', 'Russia' ,'Saudi Arabia' ,'Scotland' ,'Serbia',
 'Seychelles', 'Singapore' ,'Slovakia', 'Slovenia' ,'Spain' ,'Sweden',
 'Switzerland' ,'Turkey' ,'United Arab Emirates' ,'United Kingdom',
 'United States', 'Wales']
  

ticker = pn.widgets.Select(name='country', options=tickers)

# this creates the date range slider

date_range_slider = pn.widgets.DateRangeSlider(
name='Date Range Slider',
start=dt.datetime(2020, 12, 13), end=dt.datetime(2021, 1, 25),
value=(dt.datetime(2020, 12, 13), dt.datetime(2021, 1, 25))
)

title = 'total vaccinations per day'
subtitle = 'This dashboard allows you to select a country and date range to see total vaccinations per day.'

@pn.depends(ticker.param.value, date_range_slider.param.value)

def get_plot(ticker, date_range):
     # Load and format the data
     df = df2 # define df
     df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
     # create date filter using values from the range slider
     # store the first and last date range slider value in a var
     start_date = date_range_slider.value[0] 
     end_date = date_range_slider.value[1] 
     # create filter mask for the dataframe
     mask = (df['date'] > start_date) & (df['date'] <= end_date)
     df = df.loc[mask] # filter the dataframe
     # create the Altair chart object
     chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode( alt.X('date'),alt.Y('total_vaccinations'),      
                                              tooltip=alt.Tooltip(['date','total_vaccinations'])).transform_filter(
(datum.symbol == ticker) # this ties in the filter 
)
     return chart
dashboard = pn.Row(pn.Column(title, subtitle, ticker, date_range_slider),
get_plot # our draw chart function!
)
dashboard.servable()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1ZTW.png)

any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance

Comment: You are not using Bokeh anywhere in the above code. Please edit your code to have proper formatting, to remove all lines that are not directly relevant to the problem, and and clarify what tools you are actually trying to use.

Comment: As @bigreddot mentioned the code need to be reformatted. I tried to edit it for myself but the still I don't know exactly what is the problem here